# search content fragments with a specific tag using querybuilder api

Tags: aem, query-builder

I'm trying to get all content  fragments under dam with specific tag using querybuilder

```
type=dam:Assets
path=/content/dam/
boolproperty=jcr:content/contentFragment
boolproperty.value=true
property=cq:tags
property.value=searchKeywords:tag1
```

even though there are content fragments with the tag specified, getting Number of hits as 0
can someone help me  with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the below query in AEM 6.5

```
type=dam:Asset
    tagid=core-components-examples:component-type/reference
    tagid.property=jcr:content/metadata/cq:tags
```

I have created a content fragment inside `/content/dam/wkndmuzik` with tag `Core Components Examples : Component Type / Reference`

Output of the above query:

```
/content/dam/wkndmuzik/content_frag/testcf
```

where testcf is the title of my content fragment. For more details please refer [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/querybuilder-api.html).